# Issue while creating the record with Controlled by parent sharing setting

Tags: profile, permissions, sharing, object, owd

I have one custom object. I am trying to create the record from one of the user but getting insufficient Privileges.

sharing setting for custom object is controlled by parent.Its parent is Opportunity and Opportunity owner is the same user who is trying to create a record in custom object.Object permission is CRUD for both the objects.

Comment: Are you sure that your Custom object is Child of Opportunity and not in a `Lookup` relationship?

Comment: It is having Master-Detail(Opportunity) relationship

Comment: Kindly share your code and log as well.

Comment: Grant Access Using Hierarchies is not set

Comment: its a stnadard page.no code.just trying to create a new record in custom object which is having controlled by parent with opportunity.while creating getting error insifficient privilages.

Comment: Does your custom object has other master-detail relationship with any other object?

Comment: No.There is no any other relationships with any object

Comment: Can you actually share your snaps of sharing setting of Opportunity (parent)?

Comment: The user on which you are trying to create a record for custom object. Does the user can create an opportunity first ? Please test that

Comment: yes he is able to create opportunity